# Row count System.Data.DataTableReader

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2007, datareader

As the title says I have a datareader with multiple data that I got from a SQL setence. I just need to find out how many rows my datareader has.

I can read them all with `while datareader.read` but I can't get the times it found a value:

```
Dim sql2 As String = "select produtos.iva,fat_prods.id_fat,fat_prods.id_prod,fat_prods.quantidade,fat_prods.preco,fat_prods.id_cliente,fat_prods.descricao from fat_prods INNER JOIN produtos ON fat_prods.id_prod=produtos.id_prod WHERE fat_prods.id_fat=" + valor.ToString + ""
Dim dadosretornados2 As System.Data.DataTableReader = buscadadosacess(sql2)
```

Comment: You can't.  The whole point of a data reader is that it is read-only and forward-only.  You can't know how many records are in the result set without reading them all.  The `HasRows` property can tell you whether the count is zero but, if `HasRows` is `True`, you can't get a count without reading.  You could call `DataTable.Load` to load the results into a new `DataTable` in one go and get the row count from that.

Comment: so i always need to read all the results and count as many times he enters the reader? thanks

Comment: and if i use the count on sql sentence how can i retrieve the value of the count? 
it will be like what? data("") what value in there